# How to display 4 patterns side by side divided by line

Tags: c

I want to know the idea on how to print this, but in C:

[image: The Example]

I already did the patterns above,
and here are their codes:

---

```
for(i=1; i<=5; i++)
{
    for(j=1; j<=5; j++)
    {
        if(i==1 || i==5 || j==1 || j==5)
        {  
            printf("*");
        }
        else
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
    for(i=1; i<=5; i++)
{

    for(j=1; j<i; j++)
    {
        printf(" ");
    }

    for(j=i; j<=5; j++)
    {
        printf("*");
    } 
}
```

---

```
columns=1;

for(i=1;i<5*2;i++)
{
    for(j=1; j<=columns; j++)
    {
        printf("*");
    }

    if(i < 5)
    {

        columns++;
    }
    else
    {

        columns--;
    }
```

---

```
stars = 1;
spaces = 5- 1;

for(i=1; i<5*2; i++)
{

    for(j=1; j<=spaces; j++)
        printf(" ");


    for(j=1; j<stars*2; j++)
        printf("*");


    printf("\n");

    if(i<5)
    {
        spaces--;
        stars++;
    }
    else
    {
        spaces++;
        stars--;
    }
}
```

---

The question is how to display these patterns side by side?

Comment: Hint: use a 2D array of chars.

Comment: Can you use `ncurses`?

Comment: Don't you forgot some `printf("\n")` in your 3 firsts peace of code ? However, you may use `printf("\r     | ")` to restart writing on the same line

Comment: The pattern is not the same. The first piece of code is printing: `******   **   **   ******`. The first part in the image as 5 asterics, not 6.

Comment: Also you have 4 columns: why you are iterating 5 times? I cannot see any logical pattern: if there is can u please tell us? If not you have to treat each case independently .

Comment: Your third pattern might get a bit higher than 5x5 chars.

Comment: @FrancescoBoi each pattern has 5 rows and 5 columns. Not 4.

Comment: In the image you posted there are 4 columns:  1|2|3|4

Comment: In essence the solution is simply this. Write each pattern code in a way that uses a row number increasing from 1 to 5 (not 1 to 10). Then you can put all the code into the same `for` loop. Only the last piece of code should print newline characters.

Comment: I think it's imposssible to do all those in 1 big for loop